# Installing Linux on EZBook 2

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, arm

I've got a EZBook 2 running Windows 10. It works just fine.

I'd like to install a lightweight Linux distro on it. I'm interested in running a terminal and Chromium on it (probably Openbox?).

I have trouble booting from USB. The USB drive is detected in BIOS, but it fails to boot from the USB drive.

Do I need to install a special build (such as ARM build or so)? How can I solve this?

---

I disabled secure and fast boot in BIOS.

Comment: Atom cpu are not ARM I think, but maybe there's secureboot activated in your Bios and you will need to disable that

Comment: @Kiwy Forgot to mention that I disabled fast and secure boot.

Comment: did you tried your boot key on another computer ? Did you change boot order to boot from usb in priority ?

Comment: +1 for checking BIOS settings for boot priority; verify the usb is on the list and before other items.

Comment: @Kiwy Good point, I tried the same USB drive on my laptop and it didn't book either. Trying to use a different one.